# Numerical citation using "unsrt" bibliography style out of order

Tags: bibliographies, citing, sorting

As part of my thesis, I have a main file which imports individual chapter files using `\input{}`. However I am noticing something very strange with my chapter files. When I cite in the document itself, the citations do not appear in order within the text itself but instead jumps around. I think this issue emerges from citing in my captions, but I am unsure how I can resolve this.

My main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% Maths symbols
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{natbib}





\begin{document}
    
    \frontmatter

    


    % Include list of figures (and in table of contents)
    \newpage
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
    \listoffigures
    
    \mainmatter


    \input{Chapter5/test}

    
\end{document}
```

The `test` chapter file is:

```
\chapter[test]{test}\label{chap:lminter}

test \cite{Rakic:98,Ordal:88} 
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Chapter5/Figures/Absorptivity-altered.pdf}
        \caption{test .\cite{Rakic:98,Ordal:88} }
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\par
test test test test test \cite{copper,gold,smart} 

\par
test test test .\cite{doi:10.1116/1.570165, Sanderthinfilms} 

test test test test \cite{PhysRevB.6.4370}
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Chapter5/Figures/mucomp.pdf}
        \caption{test test test \cite{Mathewson_1971, PhysRevB.6.4370, Zndata, AgData,minissale:hal-01690700,Winsemius_1976, Al_dependence}}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\par
test test test hfhfdfdgfvdz \cite{SolidState} 
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Chapter5/Figures/ReflectivityFunc_annotate.png}
        \caption{\cite{Winsemius_1976, Reddy:16, AgData, Al_dependence}. }

    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{Chapter5/chapter5.bib}
```

And the `chapter5.bib` file is:

```
@article{braun,
    author = {Braun,Wolfgang  and Mannhart,Jochen },
    title = {Film deposition by thermal laser evaporation},
    journal = {AIP Advances},
    volume = {9},
    number = {8},
    pages = {085310},
    year = {2019},
    doi = {10.1063/1.5111678},
    
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5111678
    
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5111678
    
    }
    
}
@article{Langmuir,
    title = {The Vapor Pressure of Metallic Tungsten},
    author = {Langmuir, I.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev.},
    volume = {2},
    issue = {5},
    pages = {329--342},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1913},
    month = {Nov},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.2.329}
}
@article{DYKim_Epitaxy,
    author = {Kim,Dong Yeong  and Mannhart,Jochen  and Braun,Wolfgang },
    title = {Epitaxial film growth by thermal laser evaporation},
    journal = {Journal of Vacuum Science \& Technology A},
    volume = {39},
    number = {5},
    pages = {053406},
    year = {2021},
    doi = {10.1116/6.0001177},
    
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1116/6.0001177
    
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1116/6.0001177}
    
}

@misc{Trumpf,
    author = {{Trumpf GmbH + Co. KG, Ditzingen, Germany}},
    title = {Tru{D}isk 2000},
    howpublished = {\url{ https://www.trumpf.com/en_INT}}
}
}
@article{weld,
    title = "{P}rocess {S}tudies on {L}aser {W}elding of {C}opper with {B}rilliant {G}reen and {I}nfrared Lasers",
    journal = "Physics Procedia",
    author = "Sebastian Engler and Reiner Ramsayer and Reinhart Poprawe",
    volume = "12",
    pages = "339 - 346",
    year = "2011",
    note = "Lasers in Manufacturing 2011 - Proceedings of the Sixth International WLT Conference on Lasers in Manufacturing",
    issn = "1875-3892"
}
@book{laserheating,
    author = " A. M. Prokhorov and I. Ursu and V. I. Konov and I. N. Mihailescu",
    title = "Laser Heating of Metals",
    year = "1990",
    volume = "1",
    publisher = "IOP Publishing Ltd", 
    note = "ISBN: 0-7503-0040-X"}

@article{PhysRev.118.1509,
    title = {Optical Properties of Copper},
    author = {Roberts, S.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev.},
    volume = {118},
    issue = {6},
    pages = {1509--1518},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1960},
    month = {Jun},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.118.1509},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.118.1509}
}
@article{PhysRevB.73.075115,
    title = {Optical properties of bcc transition metals in the range $0-40\phantom{\rule{0.3em}{0ex}}\mathrm{eV}$},
    author = {Romaniello, P. and de Boeij, P. L. and Carbone, F. and van der Marel, D.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = {73},
    issue = {7},
    pages = {075115},
    numpages = {16},
    year = {2006},
    month = {Feb},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.73.075115},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.73.075115}
}
@article{PhysRevLett.49.1955,
    title = {Laser-{I}nduced {P}eriodic {S}urface {S}tructure on {S}olids: {A} {U}niversal {P}henomenon},
    author = {van Driel, H. M. and Sipe, J. E. and Young, Jeff F.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
    volume = {49},
    issue = {26},
    pages = {1955--1958},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1982},
    month = {Dec},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.49.1955},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.49.1955}
}
@article{SIM20051137,
    title = "Melting and dynamic-surface deformation in laser surface heating",
    journal = "International Journal of Heat and Mass Transfer",
    volume = "48",
    number = "6",
    pages = "1137 - 1144",
    year = "2005",
    issn = "0017-9310",
    author = "Bok-Cheol Sim and Woo-Seung Kim"
}
@misc{vapour,
    title = {{TU} {V}ienna {V}apor {P}ressure {C}alculator},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.iap.tuwien.ac.at/www/surface/vapor_pressure}},
    note = {Accessed: 2020-03-20}}

@book{tilley2019colour,
    title={Colour and the Optical Properties of Materials},
    author={Tilley, R.J.D.},
    note={ISBN: 9781119554684},
    lccn={2019030286},
    volume = "3",
    year={2019},
    publisher={Wiley}
}
@book{SolidState,
    author = {Kuzmany, Hans},
    year = {2009},
    title = {{S}olid-{S}tate {S}pectroscopy: {A}n {I}ntroduction},
    journal = {Solid-State Spectroscopy: An Introduction},
    publisher = {Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg},
    note = {ISBN: 978-3-642-01478-9.}
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-01479-6}
}
@article{copper,
    title = {Energy {B}and {S}tructure of {C}opper},
    author = {Burdick, Glenn A.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev.},
    volume = {129},
    issue = {1},
    pages = {138--150},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1963},
    month = {Jan},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.129.138},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.129.138}
}
@article{gold,
    author = {Rangel, Tonatiuh and Keçik, Deniz and Trevisanutto, Paolo and Rignanese, G.-M and van Swygenhoven, Helena and Olevano, Valerio},
    year = {2012},
    month = {03},
    pages = {},
    title = {Band structure of gold from many-body perturbation theory},
    volume = {86},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.86.125125}
}
@book{ellipsometry,
    author = " R. M. A. Azzam and N. M. Bashara",
    title = "Ellipsometry and polarized light",
    year = "1987",
    volume = "2",
    publisher = "North-Holland, Amsterdam", 
    note = "ISBN: 0720406943"}

@article{Rakic:98,
    author = {Aleksandar D. Raki\'{c} and Aleksandra B. Djuri\v{s}i\'{c} and Jovan M. Elazar and Marian L. Majewski},
    journal = {Appl. Opt.},
    number = {22},
    pages = {5271--5283},
    publisher = {OSA},
    title = {Optical properties of metallic films for vertical-cavity optoelectronic devices},
    volume = {37},
    month = {Aug},
    year = {1998},
    url = {http://ao.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-37-22-5271},
    doi = {10.1364/AO.37.005271}
}   
@article{Ordal:88,
    author = {Mark A. Ordal and Robert J. Bell and Ralph W. Alexander and Lawrence A. Newquist and Marvin R. Querry},
    journal = {Appl. Opt.},
    number = {6},
    pages = {1203--1209},
    publisher = {OSA},
    title = {Optical properties of {A}l, {F}e, {T}i, {T}a, {W}, and {M}o at submillimeter wavelengths},
    volume = {27},
    month = {Mar},
    year = {1988},
    url = {http://ao.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-27-6-1203},
    doi = {10.1364/AO.27.001203}
}
@article{nanoparticles,
    author = {Mendoza Herrera,Luis J.  and Arboleda,David Muñetón  and Schinca,Daniel C.  and Scaffardi,Lucía B. },
    title = {Determination of plasma frequency, damping constant, and size distribution from the complex dielectric function of noble metal nanoparticles},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
    volume = {116},
    number = {23},
    pages = {233105},
    year = {2014},
    doi = {10.1063/1.4904349}
    
}

@article{dampingdep,
    title = {Frequency dependence of the optical relaxation time in metals},
    author = {Smith, Jeffrey B. and Ehrenreich, H.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = {25},
    issue = {2},
    pages = {923--930},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1982},
    month = {Jan},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.25.923},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.25.923}
}
@article{smart,
    title = {Thermal laser evaporation of elements from across the periodic table},
    author = {Smart, Thomas J. and Mannhart, Jochen and Braun, Wolfgang},
    journal = {Journal of Laser Applications},
    volume = {33},
    issue = {2},
    pages = {02205},
    year = {2021},
    month = {Mar},
    doi = {10.2351/7.0000348},
}
@article{noblemetalsreview,
    author = {Suffczynski, M.},
    title = {Optical Properties of the Noble Metals},
    journal = {Physica Status Solidi (b)},
    volume = {4},
    number = {1},
    pages = {3-29},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1002/pssb.19640040102},
    year = {1964}
}
@article{PhysRevB.6.4370,
    title = {Optical Constants of the Noble Metals},
    author = {Johnson, P. B. and Christy, R. W.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = {6},
    issue = {12},
    pages = {4370--4379},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1972},
    month = {Dec},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.6.4370},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.6.4370}
}
@article{Mathewson_1971,
    doi = {10.1088/0031-8949/4/6/009},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1088/0031-8949/4/6/009},
    year = 1971,
    month = {dec},
    publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
    volume = {4},
    number = {6},
    pages = {291--292},
    author = {A G Mathewson and H P Myers},
    title = {Absolute Values of the Optical Constants of Some Pure Metals},
    journal = {Physica Scripta},
    abstract = {Without abstract; see full text}
}
@article{PEIPONEN1990127,
    title = {Metal surface roughness and optical reflectance},
    journal = {Optics & Laser Technology},
    volume = {22},
    number = {2},
    pages = {127-130},
    year = {1990},
    issn = {0030-3992},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/0030-3992(90)90022-V},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/003039929090022V},
    author = {K.-E. Peiponen and T. Tsuboi}
}
@article{Zndata,
    author = {Werner,Wolfgang S. M.  and Glantschnig,Kathrin  and Ambrosch-Draxl,Claudia},
    title = {Optical {C}onstants and {I}nelastic {E}lectron {S}cattering {D}ata for 17 {E}lemental {M}etals},
    journal = {Journal of Physical and Chemical Reference Data},
    volume = {38},
    number = {4},
    pages = {1013-1092},
    year = {2009},
    doi = {10.1063/1.3243762}
}
@article{Zn-VP,
    author = { A.C. Egerton },
    title = {The vapour pressure of zinc, cadmium, and mercury},
    journal = {The London, Edinburgh, and Dublin Philosophical Magazine and Journal of Science},
    volume = {33},
    number = {193},
    pages = {33-48},
    year  = {1917},
    publisher = {Taylor & Francis},
    doi = {10.1080/14786440108635614}
}
@article{minissale:hal-01690700,
    TITLE = {{The temperature dependence of optical properties of tungsten in the visible and near-infrared domains: an experimental and theoretical study}},
    AUTHOR = {Minissale, Marco and Pardanaud, C{\'e}dric and Bisson, R{\'e}gis and Gallais, Laurent},
    URL = {https://hal-amu.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01690700},
    JOURNAL = {{Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics}},
    PUBLISHER = {{IOP Publishing}},
    VOLUME = {50},
    NUMBER = {45},
    YEAR = {2017},
    MONTH = Nov,
    DOI = {10.1088/1361-6463/aa81f3},
    PDF = {https://hal-amu.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01690700/file/JPD_AppliedPhys_Minissale%20postprint.pdf},
    HAL_ID = {hal-01690700},
    HAL_VERSION = {v1}
}
@article{Winsemius_1976,
    doi = {10.1088/0305-4608/6/8/017},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4608/6/8/017},
    year = 1976,
    month = {aug},
    publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
    volume = {6},
    number = {8},
    pages = {1583--1606},
    author = {P Winsemius and F F van Kampen and H P Lengkeek and C G van Went},
    title = {Temperature dependence of the optical properties of {A}u, {A}g and {C}u},
    journal = {Journal of Physics F: Metal Physics}
}
@article{Winsemius_Ag,
    author = {Winsemius, P.},
    title = {Temperature dependence of the optical properties {A}g: The {X}-point},
    journal = {physica status solidi (b)},
    volume = {59},
    number = {1},
    pages = {K55-K58},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1002/pssb.2220590153},
    url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pssb.2220590153},
    eprint = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/pssb.2220590153},
    year = {1973}
}
@article{AgSpectra,
    author = {Sundari,S. Tripura  and Chandra,Sharat  and Tyagi,A. K. },
    title = {Temperature dependent optical properties of silver from spectroscopic ellipsometry and density functional theory calculations},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
    volume = {114},
    number = {3},
    pages = {033515},
    year = {2013},
    doi = {10.1063/1.4813874},
    
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4813874
    
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4813874
    
    }
    
}
@article{AgData,
    author = {Reddy, Harsha and Guler, Urcan and Chaudhuri, Krishnakali and Dutta, Aveek and Kildishev, Alexander V. and Shalaev, Vladimir M. and Boltasseva, Alexandra},
    title = {Temperature-{D}ependent {O}ptical {P}roperties of {S}ingle {C}rystalline and {P}olycrystalline {S}ilver {T}hin {F}ilms},
    journal = {ACS Photonics},
    volume = {4},
    number = {5},
    pages = {1083-1091},
    year = {2017},
    doi = {10.1021/acsphotonics.6b00886},
    
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1021/acsphotonics.6b00886
    
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1021/acsphotonics.6b00886
    
    }
    
}
@article{nanoparticles,
    author = {Mendoza Herrera,Luis J.  and Arboleda,David Muñetón  and Schinca,Daniel C.  and Scaffardi,Lucía B. },
    title = {Determination of plasma frequency, damping constant, and size distribution from the complex dielectric function of noble metal nanoparticles},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
    volume = {116},
    number = {23},
    pages = {233105},
    year = {2014},
    doi = {10.1063/1.4904349}
    
}
@book{plasmonics,
    author = {Maier, S.A.},
    title = {Plasmonics: {F}undamentals and {A}pplications},
    publisher = {Springer},
    note = {ISBN: 978-0-387-33150-8},
    year = {2007},
    
}

@article{Reddy:16,
    author = {Harsha Reddy and Urcan Guler and Alexander V. Kildishev and Alexandra Boltasseva and Vladimir M. Shalaev},
    journal = {Opt. Mater. Express},
    number = {9},
    pages = {2776--2802},
    publisher = {OSA},
    title = {Temperature-dependent optical properties of gold thin films},
    volume = {6},
    month = {Sep},
    year = {2016},
    doi = {10.1364/OME.6.002776}
}
@article{Al_dependence,
    author = { Kalenskii, A. V. and Zvekov, A. A.},
    year = {2017},
    title = {Temperature dependences of the optical properties of aluminum nanoparticles},
    journal = {Technical Physics Letters},
    volume = {43},
    issue = {6},
    doi = {10.1134/S1063785017060098}
}
@article{PhysRev.132.1918,
    title = {Optical {P}roperties of {A}luminum},
    author = {Ehrenreich, H. and Philipp, H. R. and Segall, B.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev.},
    volume = {132},
    issue = {5},
    pages = {1918--1928},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1963},
    month = {Dec},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.132.1918},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.132.1918}
}
@article{doi:10.1116/1.570165,
    author = {König,U.  and Kibbel,H.  and Kasper,E. },
    title = {Si–{MBE}: {G}rowth and {S}b doping},
    journal = {Journal of Vacuum Science and Technology},
    volume = {16},
    number = {4},
    pages = {985-989},
    year = {1979},
    doi = {10.1116/1.570165}
    
}
@article{Sanderthinfilms,
    title = {Mapping unit-cell thickness variations in thin films by post-deposition reflection high-energy electron diffraction},
    author = {Smink, A. E. M. and Birkh\"olzer, Y. A. and van Dam, J. and Roesthuis, F. J. G. and Rijnders, G. and Hilgenkamp, H. and Koster, G.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. Materials},
    volume = {4},
    issue = {8},
    pages = {083806},
    numpages = {8},
    year = {2020},
    month = {Aug},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.4.083806}
}
@article{MoTempDep,
    author = {Xu,Meng  and Yang,Jia-Yue  and Liu,Linhua },
    title = {Temperature-dependent dielectric functions of bcc transition metals {C}r, {M}o, and {W} from ultraviolet to infrared regions: {A} theoretical and experimental study},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
    volume = {123},
    number = {15},
    pages = {155102},
    year = {2018},
    doi = {10.1063/1.5023606},
    
    URL = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5023606
    
    },
    eprint = { 
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5023606
    
    }
    
}
@article{W-transition,
    title = {Optical properties of crystalline tungsten},
    author = {Weaver, J. H. and Olson, C. G. and Lynch, D. W.},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    volume = {12},
    issue = {4},
    pages = {1293--1297},
    numpages = {0},
    year = {1975},
    month = {Aug},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.12.1293},
    url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.12.1293}
}

@article{surfaceroughness,
    author = {H. E. Bennett and J. O. Porteus},
    journal = {J. Opt. Soc. Am.},
    keywords = {Diffuse reflectance; Light wavelength; Optical measurement; Surface roughness measurement; Ultraviolet radiation; Visible light},
    number = {2},
    pages = {123--129},
    publisher = {OSA},
    title = {Relation {B}etween {S}urface {R}oughness and {S}pecular {R}eflectance at {N}ormal {I}ncidence},
    volume = {51},
    year = {1961},
    url = {http://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?URI=josa-51-2-123},
    doi = {10.1364/JOSA.51.000123}
} 
@article{Hunter:65,
    author = {W. R. Hunter},
    journal = {J. Opt. Soc. Am.},
    number = {10},
    pages = {1197--1204},
    publisher = {OSA},
    title = {Errors in using the {R}eflectance vs {A}ngle of {I}ncidence {M}ethod for {M}easuring {O}ptical {C}onstants},
    volume = {55},
    month = {Oct},
    year = {1965},
    url = {http://opg.optica.org/abstract.cfm?URI=josa-55-10-1197},
    doi = {10.1364/JOSA.55.001197}
}
```

What am I specifically doing wrong here? Is there a way to ensure citations appear according to their order of appearance within the text itself?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you might as well employ the `unsrtnat` bibliography style instead of `unsrt`.

Comment: The issue you've encountered arises because your document (a) has `\cite` commands inside some `\caption` commands and (b) has a `\listoffigures` command. The best solution is to employ `\caption` directives with optional arguments that omit the `\cite` directives. E.g., change `\caption{test test test \cite{Mathewson_1971, PhysRevB.6.4370, Zndata, AgData, minissale:hal-01690700, Winsemius_1976, Al_dependence}}` to `\caption[test test test]{test test test \cite{Mathewson_1971, PhysRevB.6.4370, Zndata, AgData, minissale:hal-01690700, Winsemius_1976, Al_dependence}}`. (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) The text in the optional argument of `\caption` will be used in the List of Figures. After changing the `\caption` directives as suggested above, be sure to re-run LaTeX twice to full update all dependencies.

Comment: @Mico If I try this, then I get no change in the citation order in the text itself, rather I remove them within by list of figures. However the order of citations still jumps around within the text, i.e the order in the text goes [1], [2], [11], [12] etc.

Comment: Did you re-run BibTeX and LaTeX *twice*?

Comment: yes i did do that. In addition by changing to ```unsrtnat```, it appears to have removed the numerical citations and replaced them with ie ```Smith et al (2022)```

Comment: Ok, by removing the .aux file from my thesis, it all works now

Comment: To force `unsrtnat`, `plainnat`, and `abbrvnat` bibliography styles to generate numeric-style citation call-outs, be sure to load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`.